# Issue Creating and Freeing C Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am writing a C program that involves passing 2D arrays between functions changing their size and entries. I decided to use dynamic arrays with pointers for this.

Whenever I free the pointers to an array, I find that I wipe the values held in other arrays. I can successfully change which array a pointer points to. I believe this is an issue with the way I'm freeing my pointers or declaring them. Below is code I'm using to create and free pointers to my arrays.

```
int** create_array(int m, int n)
{
  int i;
  int* values = calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));
  int** rows = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    rows[i] = values + (i * m);
  }
  return rows;

}

void destroy_array(int** arr)
{
  free(arr[0]);
  free(arr);

}
```

*OLD CODE to Create and Free Pointers*

```
int** create_array(int m, int n)
{
  int i;
  int* values = calloc(m * n, sizeof(int));
  int** rows = malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    rows[i] = values + (i * m * sizeof(int));
  }
  return rows;

}

void destroy_array(int** arr, int m, int n)
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    free(arr[i]);
  }
  free(arr);

}
```

My program gets a segfault after I destroy the pointers to an array and try to read values from another array. Below is the code where I destroy my pointers to these arrays. positions_last and positions are both arrays that I can read from properly before this point.

```
positions_last = positions;
printf("- %d %d %d - ", positions_last[0][1], positions_last[1][1], positions_last[2][1]);
fflush(stdout); // this prints fine
destroy_array(positions);
printf("- %d %d %d - ", positions_last[0][1], positions_last[1][1], positions_last[2][1]);
fflush(stdout); // this does not print, I get a segfault at this point
```

I just did an elementary test which suggests that the issue lies in my current code for creating or destroying arrays (so far as I know).

```
int** positions2 = create_array(10, 3);
int** positions3 = create_array(10, 3);
printf("%d %d %d", positions3[0][1], positions3[1][1], positions3[2][1]);
fflush(stdout); // This line prints fine
positions3 = positions2;
destroy_array(positions2);
printf("%d %d %d", positions3[0][1], positions3[1][1], positions3[2][1]);
fflush(stdout); // This line triggers a segfault
```

Anyone have an idea what the issue may be?

Comment: Typo, you wrote free(arr[1]).

Comment: Youch.  When you `free(arr[1])` you are executing free in the middle of an allocated region.  This is very bad.  I think you need to rethink your entire design.  Why aren't you just allocating a two dimensional array rather than allocating a region to contain integers and then an array to point into it?

Comment: (Also this is just hideously wrong because the row pointers point to the middle of a big allocated block)

Comment: Don't know how the 1 got in free(arr[1]), it was i in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You called `calloc` once and `malloc` once, but then you're calling `free` n+1 times (and of course you're freeing the same value, `arr[1]` `n` times). There should be exactly one `free` for each `malloc` or `calloc`.

```
void destroy_array(int** arr)
{
  free(arr[0]);
  free(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
rows[i] = values + (i * m * sizeof(int));
```

should be

```
rows[i] = values + (i * m);
```

The reason behind this is that `values` is a typed pointer, namely pointing to `int`. Adding `1` to it increases it by `1 * sizeof (int)`. Your code assumes it would be increased by  `1` only.

This are basic pointer arithmetics: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/104/ ;-)

So you are running into undefined behaviuor even before the 1st call to `free()`.

---

Also `malloc`/`calloc` and `free` follow the pattern:

> One Allocation --> One Freeing

So freeing might look like this:

```
free(*arr); /* Free what had been allocated to "values". */
free(arr); /* Free what had been allocated to "rows". */
```

The code you show does differently, as pointed out by *[zindorsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460285/zindorsky)*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30106687/694576).

---

Regarding your edit:

This

```
positions_last = positions;
```

does not copy the array, its elements, but just the reference to the array 1st member. SO if you deallocate `positions` also `positions_last` points to freed, that is then invalif memory. Accessing it provokes UB, as this lines does:

```
printf("- %d %d %d - ", positions_last[0][1], positions_last[1][1], positions_last[2][1]);
```

Lesson learned: In C one cannot copy an array by a simple assignment

Comment: I made this edit and zindorsky's and I am still encountering a segfault. I had something like that before, but I became unsure of my code when I ran into a error where the values in one of my arrays got wiped when another, seemingly unrelated one, was freed. I will add the part of code where my values get wiped.